# How many spell-bearing items can you activate in a turn?

Tags: spells, magic-items, anima-beyond-fantasy

In the Prometheum Exxet, there are two means of creating an item that can cast a spell: Items with the Automatic Spells power, which require no Zeon and have to recharge, and items with the Spellcaster power, which do require Zeon.

How many of each type of item can you activate in a turn, assuming you have three actions and indefinite magic accumulation?

Answer (score -1):

Automatic spells based on their trigger don't have a limit. Spell-caster powers is tied to your action limit, found on page 80, table 37 of the core book.

Comment: Wait, seriously?  If anything I would have thought it's the other way around.

Comment: If the trigger is "Im falling", then it can activate even if the person using the item is unconscious. "Spellcasting" behaves differently in that they have activation procedures to use their powers.

Comment: I think you might need to look up the rules - I'm talking about two methods of item-making with those names, not...literally *automatic* spells.  I'd *love* to be able to make literally automatic spells, but I certainly cannot construct them.